# can sort some arrays but not others?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I'm sorting the lines of a text box in reverse alphabetical order, and the code I have works fine:

```
string[] temp = textBox.Lines;
Array.Sort(temp);
Array.Reverse(temp);
textBox.Lines = temp;
```

But I'm confused as to why Visual Studio wouldn't let me do:

```
Array.Sort(textBox.Lines);
Array.Reverse(textBox.Lines);
```

Mostly I'm trying to figure out the subtleties of C# since I'm still new to it.

EDIT: The second snippet doesn't error out, but it doesn't execute any code (i.e. doesn't appear to do anything).

Comment: It *will* let you do those things...

Comment: What happens when you try the second snippet?

Comment: See notes in the docs : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What you trying to achieve here?

Comment: To your edit, you say that it doesn't execute any code, but it *does* execute code.  The problem is simply that reading the lines again doesn't result in sorted lines.  *That* is the problem you are having, which is actually contrary to what you have stated the problem is.

Comment: @Servy I worded that poorly; edited for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a few lines of the getter for `TextBox.Lines`:

```
public string[] Lines
{ 
    get
    { 
        string text = Text;
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        ...
        ...

        return(string[]) list.ToArray(typeof(string));
    }
```

You're getting a new collection, which has a *copy* of the data in it from the `TextBox`. You're not actually sorting the data in the `TextBox`.

When `void Array.Sort` is done sorting the array passed back from that property, the original `TextBox` remains unchanged.

Comment: Other answers were correct as well but yours was clearest. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, your array will be sorted and reversed, but what happens is that will not be assigned to `TextBox`. Modifying the `Lines` array has no effect since it is computed property.

You need to assign it to `Lines` property to see the effect.

Here is the reference to [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs#37cabfde1449b18f#references)

Answer (score 0):

This is because textBox.Lines is not exposed as a member variable on the class but rather as a property.  Behind the scenes, a property is really two methods, e.g. get_Lines and set_Lines.  All you know about the array you get back from get_Lines is that it's an array of strings.  There's no guarantee that that property is backed by an actual array--maybe TextBox keeps the text internally as one big string that it then breaks into pieces for you when you call get_Lines.  So you're not necessarily modifying the internal list when you call Sort() and Reverse() on the result of get_Lines.

Comment: And why is that relevant?  You most certainly *can* pass the results of a property getter into `Array.Sort` or `Array.Reverse`.  If it were a value type it would be mutating a copy, but arrays aren't value types, they're reference types, and the arrays are being mutated here, rather than a new array being constructed.

Comment: It's relevant for the reasons I cite in my answer, which I've expanded on since first posting.  Curious why this is getting downvotes.

Comment: It's getting downvotes because you posted an *incorrect answer* and then edited it at a later point in time.  Had you posted a correct answer from the start, that wouldn't have happened.

Comment: +1 I must admit I had a similar response to Servy when I read your first answer. Your update clarifies and pretty much nails it.

Comment: Servy, what I posted was correct. I only added text, didn't remove or change anything I wrote.  All the extra text did was explain why your comment was wrong.

Comment: @adv12 All of the text that you had before your edit was, and still is, entirely irrelevant to the answer at hand.  That `Lines` is a property is not a problem at all.  The only thing that is relevant to this answer is that it is a copy of the *actual* data, rather than the data itself.  While your original revision wasn't stating incorrect facts, it was an incorrect answer to the question because the information that you did provide was not the reason for the problem at hand.